# Using ampersands and parens when calling a Perl sub

Tags: perl

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

sub t {
  print "in t\n";
  print "@_\n";
  &s;
}

sub s {
  print "in s\n";
  print "@_\n";
}

t(1,2);
print "out\n";
print "@_\n";
```

Output:

```
in t
1 2
in s
1 2
out
```

As you see,`&s` output `1 2` when no parameter is passed. Is this a feature or a bug?

Tested version is 5.8.8.

Comment: The real question is, is Perl a feature or a bug?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Calling a subroutine using the `&NAME;` syntax makes current `@_` visible to it. This is documented in [perlsub](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlsub.html):

> If a subroutine is called using the `&` form, the argument list is optional, and if omitted, no `@_` array is set up for the subroutine: the `@_` array at the time of the call is visible to subroutine instead. This is an efficiency mechanism that new users may wish to avoid.

So, it's definitely a feature.

Comment: Worth noting also that the `@_` is the SAME array as in the calling subroutine, so if the called subroutine changes `@_` with `shift` or something like that, then the changes will be visible in `@_` after the call. (which is where the efficiency comes from)

Comment: And worth noting also that using `goto &mysub` you can do a *jump* instead of a *call*, which means that the current stack frame is discarded, thus not wasting memory. That way you can code loops recursively, tail-recursively, to be more exact. See [`goto &NAME`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/goto.html).

Answer (score 18):

When using `&` before the sub name and no argument list is passed, the current `@_` is passed as argument instead. So, it is a feature.

Here are the different ways to call a subroutine:

```
NAME(LIST); # & is optional with parentheses.
NAME LIST;  # Parentheses optional if predeclared/imported.
&NAME(LIST); # Circumvent prototypes.
&NAME;      # Makes current @_ visible to called subroutine.
```

from [perldoc perlsub](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlsub.html)

Comment: what do you mean by `Circumvent prototypes` here?

Comment: `sub foo ($$) { }`, the parens declare the prototype. The easiest thing to remember is: use name(LIST), unless you have a reason not to.

Comment: I listed all the possible ways to call a sub, which is a quote from perlsub. Look it up.

Comment: I think you confused yourself. The 4 things I listed was to give you an overview on how one can call a sub, and what they mean.

Answer (score 2):

Straight from the camel's mouth:

> If a subroutine is called using the ``&'' form, the argument list is optional, and if omitted, no @_ array is set up for the subroutine: the @_ array at the time of the call is visible to subroutine instead. This is an efficiency mechanism that new users may wish to avoid.