# why the syntax `&name arg1 arg2 ...` can't be used to call a Perl subroutine?

Tags: perl, syntax, subroutine, invocation

for a Perl subroutine, if passing 0 argument, I can use 4 forms to call it. But if passing 1 or more arguments, there is one form that I can't use, please see below:

```
sub name
{
    print "hello\n";
}
# 4 forms to call
name;
&name;
name();
&name();

sub aname
{
        print "@_\n";
}
aname "arg1", "arg2";
#&aname "arg1", "arg2"; # syntax error
aname("arg1", "arg2");
&aname("arg1", "arg2");
```

The error output is

```
String found where operator expected at tmp1.pl line 16, near "&aname "arg1""
    (Missing operator before  "arg1"?)
syntax error at tmp1.pl line 16, near "&aname "arg1""
Execution of tmp1.pl aborted due to compilation errors.
```

Can someone explain the error output from the compiler's point of view? I don't understand why it complains about missing operator.

Thanks

Comment: You got a great answer.  For a lot more discussion about the use of `&` for this see [`this post`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1347396/when-should-i-use-the-to-call-a-perl-subroutine), and [`this post`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8912049/difference-between-function-and-function-in-perl), and [`this post`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6706882/using-ampersands-and-parens-when-calling-a-perl-sub) ... and there are probably others.

Comment: @zdim just wondering, why did you put the links in code markup?

Comment: @simbabque  Hah, good point.  I suppose so that they are more visible, highlighted.  Don't really know. Never really thought about it as "code markup" (you are right, it is) -- but more as of highlight.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It's documented in [perlsub](http://p3rl.org/perlsub):

> To call subroutines:
>
> ```
>        NAME(LIST);    # & is optional with parentheses.
>        NAME LIST;     # Parentheses optional if predeclared/imported.
>        &NAME(LIST);   # Circumvent prototypes.
>        &NAME;         # Makes current @_ visible to called subroutine.
> ```

With `&NAME "arg"`, perl sees `&NAME() "ARG"`, so it thinks there's an operator missing between the sub call and "ARG".

In Perl 5, you don't need the `&` in most cases.